# Error opening Java node in SQL Developer (Oracle Database 12c)

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I'm using the latest version of SQL Developer (4.1.3.20 Build MAIN-20.78) and I'm having trouble opening the Java node in the Connections panel.

I recently compiled a class on oracle database 12c. It's simple class for listing a directory that compiles without errors.

```
create or replace and compile java source named "DirList"
as
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DirList
{
 public static void getList(String directory)
          throws SQLException
{
  File path = new File( directory );
  String[] list = path.list();
  String element;

  for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
  {
    element = list[i];
    #sql { INSERT INTO LIST_INPUT_DIR (FILENAME)
        VALUES (:element) };
  }
 }

};
/
```

The class is visible immediately in SQL Developer connections panel.

[image: Opened Java node]

After disconnecting&connecting again I cannot open the Java node any more. The error given is:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
No more data to read from socket
Vendor code 17410
```

The connection to the database is lost.

I know that the class is still there because I can select it with:

```
SELECT
 object_name, object_type, status, timestamp
FROM 
 user_objects
WHERE 
(object_name NOT LIKE 'SYS_%' AND 
 object_name NOT LIKE 'CREATE$%' AND 
 object_name NOT LIKE 'JAVA$%' AND 
 object_name NOT LIKE 'LOADLOB%'
) 
AND object_type LIKE 'JAVA %'
ORDER BY
 object_type, 
 object_name;
```

How can I access/see the Java classes(and sources) in the schema? Is there any other way than using connections panels?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can access the node with a workaround.

1. **Connect** to the scheme and open Java node -> Error is given
2. Right click on the connection node and **Reconnect**
3. Right click on Java node and refresh it.
4. Java classed are listed and available to open the source code in main windows.